# advantages of using camel components with hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, apache-camel

what are the advantages of using camel components with hibernate?i am implemeting hibernate in springs without camel components.Can you please suggest shall i continue the same or implement it using camel???

Comment: Gosh I wish stack overflow had a screening or a QA section where people had to do a bit work before getting in. Seeing a user with the name user135585, I cannot take seriously.

Comment: Claus its not about the name in stackoverflow.Kindly do not go on name.Its better to concentrate and help each other through this forum :).

Comment: Can you add a description of the usecase? Such as adding a scenario where a message based integration framework like Camel would fit a need. Adding framework layers won't add nothing but complexity. Are you using hibernate for inter/intra application integration or event routing?

Answer (score 1):

Do not use any framework **just for the sake of using it**. Read about the **Apache Camel** in the project [homepage](http://camel.apache.org/) and decide if it is of any use for you.

With my experience I have never used it along with **Hibernate**. So, Unless there is a specific need I would advice you not to use it.

Comment: What do you mean by specific need?? Does camel framework fulfills some specific need in combination with hibernate????

Comment: you should be fine with only hibernate. You can read the API to understand what it Apache camel is.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Camel is an integration framework. If you have some message coming from JMS and you need to save it into file, then read from DB and answer to some other component via WS, then it's your case.

Hibernate component can be used in Camel in order to store/retrieve messages. So if you just need to work with database, you don't need to work with Apache Camel.

Comment: you mean to say hibernate component in camel can only be used to store/retrieve the messages?? I guess this can be done simply without camel framework...Am i right????

Comment: Well, first of all you should read about Camel Messages, it's a class that can contain the payload and the payload itself can be stored. Then, you should understand that Hibernate Component is not for alone using, it's for Camel and for storing its messages if you need to use DB as your endpoint, not for arbitrary requirements. Read also about Enterprise Integration Patterns. From your question I understand that you don't know what Camel is for which means you shouldn't use it.